# Prev/Next Navigation with Category Name in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have done prev/next in single.php for Wordpress:

```
<?php the_post_navigation
( 
    array(
        'prev_text'          => '<p>Previous:</p><p>%title</p>',
        'next_text'          => '<p>Next:</p><p>%title</p>'
    ) 
);
```

Is it possible to show category names for prev/next posts?
(Didn't find anything about this in Wordpress Codex)

It would be like:

> Previous: (CategoryA) An Old Post Title
>   Next: (CategoryB) Another Post Title

Thanks!

Comment: you can pass taxonomy `'taxonomy' => __( 'category' )`, and `'in_same_term'  => true` so next/prev post will come from same term of post you currently on.

Comment: Thank you for the hints and I'm sorry that I didn't ask clearly.
I want to show Prev/Next posts' category names.